# Swift 2.0 Declaring UINavigationController before AppDelegate

Tags: xcode, uinavigationcontroller, swift2, ios9, xcode7

In my application i declare my navigation Controller Prior to my app delegate class, it has worked fine over ios7 and iOS 8. But once it came time to upgrade to iOS 9 and Xcode 7, it doesn't seem to want to work.

When my navigation controller is declared before my app delegate class like the following:

```
var navigationController = UINavigationController()

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
```

It doesn't allow me to access my navigation controller in my application did finish launching function:

```
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    let rootViewController: ViewController = ViewController()
    navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootViewController)
    navigationController.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
    navigationController.view.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    navigationController.view.layer.masksToBounds = true
    //navigationController.shouldAutomaticallyForwardRotationMethods()
    window!.rootViewController = navigationController
    window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

What's Stumping me is i can call my navigation controller in any other view with no problem. And also prior to Xcode 7, iOS 9, and swift 2 this also worked fine.

Did something change to swift to not allow this? How do I continue using my navigation controller like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not quite sure why but to fix this all i had to do was take out `UINavigationControllerDelegate` in the app Delegate